# If a functor creates limits, then it also reflects them

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Exercise 5.3.10 from Leinster:

> Prove that if a functor creates limits, then it also reflects them.

Here's what I have so far (the question is at the end):

Let $F:\mathscr A\to \mathscr B$ be a functor which creates limits and let $D:I\to \mathscr A$ be a diagram (=functor). Consider a cone $(A, f_i:A\to D(i))_{i\in I}$. Assume that its image under $F$, namely $(F(A), F(f_i):A\to FD(i))_{i\in I}$, is a limit cone on $F\circ D$. Need to prove that $(A, f_i:A\to D(i))_{i\in I}$ is a limit cone on $D$.

Since $F$ creates limits, there is a cone $(L, p_i:L\to D(i))_{i\in I}$ on $D$ such that $F(p_i)=F(f_i), F(L)=F(A)$, and this cone is a limit cone on $D$. It follows that there is a unique arrow $\alpha: A\to L$ such that $p_i\circ \alpha= f_i$ for all $i\in I$. So for any $i, j$ for which there is an arrow $i\to j$ in $I$, we have the following picture (on the left):

[image]

After taking $F$, we get the picture on the right. That picture implies that $F(\alpha)$ is the identity arrow. How to proceed? If we knew that $A=L$ then we could conclude that $\alpha=id$ (since $id$ must go to $id$, and $id$ is the only arrow from $A$ to $L$; but we wouldn't even need that since $A$ would be the limit automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to draw any diagrams for this question. By definition of creating limits in Leinster (see Remark 5.3.7), any cone which maps to the limit cone must itself be a limit cone. Since $(A, f_i)_{i \in I}$ is certainly a cone which does so, it must be a limit cone and $F$ reflects limits.

If you want to use the strict definition (Def 5.3.5), it follows from uniqueness of the cone that $(L, p_i)_{i \in I}$ is the same cone as $(A, f_i)_{i \in I}$, and the result follows.

Comment: To make sure I understood correctly, is the following logic correct? We take a cone $(A, f_i)$ on $D$ and assume that its image $(F(A), F(f_i))$ is a limit cone on $F\circ D$. Then we use the first bullet point in Def. 5.3.5, which says that there is a unique cone on $D$ whose image under $F$ is $(F(A), F(f_i))$. Since we know that $(A, f_i)$ gets mapped to $(F(A), F(f_i))$ under $F$, the cone $(A, f_i)$ is that unique cone from the first bullet point of Def. 5.3.5. And only after this observation, we apply the second bullet point of Def. 5.3.5 and conclude that $(A, f_i)$ is a limit of $D$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. (10 chars)